# Microphone capturing game/desktop audio

Tags: audio, microphone

This just happened to me recently but for some reason my microphone is picking up my desktop/game audio and other people can hear it if I'm in a voice chat... I looked over youtube for answers but the only thing I mainly found is that to turn off "listen to device" but mine is already off so can anyone help me solve this problem